# How do I get the background-image of a div/element in webbrowser?

Tags: html, dom, vb6, webbrowser-control

I have an element/tag/div in vb6 in the webbrowser that seems to have a background image applied to a div when it is rendered. I think it is injected via a script. I would like to get the style info for the `div`.

I've tried `.Style` on an element and it returns a  `MSCurrentStyleCSSProperties` object which I can't figure a way to iterate. This could also be the wrong way to get this info.

The background style is usually a url.  If I have `Style.backgroundImage` on an element then that only gets the initial style info. I want the 'computedstyle' I think.

The code so far is more air code:

```
Dim x
For Each x In WebBrowser2.document.getElementsByTagName("*")
'do something with the object to get the style info
'do somthing with x.Style  ' x.Style returns MSCurrentStyleCSSProperties

next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each x In WebBrowser2.document.getElementsByTagName("*")
   x.currentStyle.backgroundImage
Next
```

returns the string

> url("pathToFile.jpg")

or other possible background-image values including the string 'none'.

The gotcha is that javascript manipulated dom doesn't signal when it has finished in the IE webbrowser in vb6. DocumentComplete and DownloadComplete events are only the start of the rendering. I used a timeout timer delay before the element iteration loop. Basically, you have to wait an unknown time to see the background images in the javascript manipulated dom.